# MVC Save Changes of Modifying Roles

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, roles

Im going to save changes the modifying roles by the admin of the selected user

this below is the [HTTPPPOST] code for edit save changes

```
  public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model,ApplicationUser x, Dictionary<string, IdentityRole> roles)
    {
        var tes = string.Join(",", x.Roles.Select(y => roles[y.RoleId].Name));
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = model.Username,
                Email = model.Username,
            };
            //var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            //if (result.Succeeded)
            //{
            //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //}
            //AddErrors(result);

            //model.UserId = x.Id;
            //model.Username = x.Email;
            //model.Roles = string.Join(",",x.Roles.Select(y=> roles[y.RoleId].Name));
            _context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

AND THIS IS THE USERVIEWMODEL that i have

```
 private UserViewModel ConvertToUserViewModel(ApplicationUser x, Dictionary<string, IdentityRole> roles)
    {
        return new UserViewModel()
        {
            UserId = x.Id,
            Username = x.Email,
            Roles = string.Join(",", x.Roles.Select(y => roles[y.RoleId].Name))
        };
    }
```

and this is what is going to be like, but im failed to save this one

[IMAGES SAMPLE EDIT ROLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krUcf.jpg)

Im going to make this user as admin but i failed, how to solve this ? thank you very much